# Publishing message having same messageId to Anypoint MQ

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb

I am creating custom messageId for each message published to MQ, but for few messages same messageId is generated.

How Anypoint MQ process message having same messageId in FIFO and standard queue?

I don't want to create duplicate records. Also, Want to keep the last copy of the message and discard the older one.
Any idea, how can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you generating custom Message Id and sent it to Queue?, setting messageId or correlationId?

Comment: By setting messageId

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour sounds like exactly what you want - The ID of an Anypoint MQ message must be unique. Make sure to choose a unique custom ID to avoid unwanted side effects of duplicated IDs. In FIFO queues, messages with duplicate IDs are overwritten.

But if your message has already been read, then The ID is free to use again.